# extract modulus and exponent from public key xml in python

Tags: python, xml, rsa, public-key, modulus

I have a public key xml string in the form

```
<RSAPublicKey> <Modulus>ANG9SxVyOA8IX9mRi5Q6sH/z04fvrsLLrAf3ooAGRiETNB1TZfZ/ZWhpw9RLYPcf3J+kaqQneHEMS9OGuIYxa0rUwVYtKjSjRp8y+XNm3sODNqD4zPjqMh6wThOug5Gg/M1+ZXlkXvszmAwiXlImDqp2nH+ZFVnrREVZ1U7WKUc5</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAPublicKey>.
```

How do I extract the modulus out from this xml string in Python? e.g. i should get `ANG9SxVyOA8IX9mRi5Q6sH/z04fvrsLLrAf3ooAGRiETNB1TZfZ/ZWhpw9RLYPcf3J+kaqQneHEMS9OGuIYxa0rUwVYtKjSjRp8y+XNm3sODNqD4zPjqMh6wThOug5Gg/M1+ZXlkXvszmAwiXlImDqp2nH+ZFVnrREVZ1U7WKUc5` after the operation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post code you've tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Element tree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.ElementTree(file="yourxml.xml")
RSAPublicKey = root.findall("./RSAPublicKey") # this search all RSAPublickey
for item in RSAPublicKey :
    Modulus= item .findall("./Modulus") #in rsapublic key modulus
    print Modulus
```